# How do I make a highlighting triangle using CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a mobile UI. It has a highlighting triangle on the top left corner, but I don't know a better way to implement it. The triangle part is marked in the red rectangle area. Can anyone help?
[image: ui design]

Comment: Please post some code otr snippet to the example. So you goal is to highlight the arrow/triangle?

Comment: can u plz some examples what u expect? its possible to highlight the section in mobile view.. This is the one simple way to highlight https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @Phanti This is a sketch design. Right now I don't have code snippets for this one because I'm stuck implementing the triangle (the big one covers the background, not the arrow button).

Comment: I'm not sure if the "highlighting" word used correctly. All I wanted is to implement that big transparent, gradient filled, top left triangle which covers the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
      body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .common-class{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #3f41e8;
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .triangle{
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-top: 180px solid #484ae5;
   border-right: 180px solid transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div class ="common-class">
 <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the triangle has a gradient effect. Could you add that?

Comment: okay. i will update it.

Comment: add .common-class{background-color: #3f41e8;} & .triangle{ border-top: 180px solid #484ae5;}.

This should work

Comment: I mean, the triangle itself is gradient-filled, might from "#3B37DE" to transparent, not a slide color. Can this be implemented using pure CSS? The border color does not seem to support linear-gradient function.